# Node.js: How to download a file via an HTTPS/POST request

Tags: node.js, https, http-post

I'm trying to download a file from www.borsaistanbul.com
For some file (like the ones under the link=> https://www.borsaistanbul.com/veriler/verileralt/hisse-senetleri-piyasasi-verileri/bulten-verileri ) they've provided the file paths so I was able to download them via https.get(downloadLink) easily.

But for the files under https://www.borsaistanbul.com/veriler/verileralt/hisse-senetleri-piyasasi-verileri/piyasa-verileri they don't provide the paths and the download links. 
I'm trying to download the one named "Üye Bazında Seanslık İşlem Sıralaması"(the one on the 2nd row)
I might be wrong but as far as I understand, when you click on the download image next to it, your browser makes a POST request and then it triggers smth on the server side and then server serves the file to you.
I've found the POST request with the help of chromeDeveloper tool and tried to simulate it but it does not seem to work.
Could anyone helps and shows me a way how to download this file ?

Here is a sample code I've tried:

```
fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
/* Create an empty file where we can save data */
let file = fs.createWriteStream(`denemePost.zip`);
/* Using Promises so that we can use the ASYNC AWAIT syntax */        

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let stream = request.post({
        /* Here you should specify the exact link to the file you are trying to download */
        uri: 'https://www.borsaistanbul.com/veriler/verileralt/hisse-senetleri-piyasasi-verileri/bulten-verileri',
        headers: {
            // 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            // 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6,la;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4,de;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length' : '7511',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cookie' : 'ASP.NET_SessionId=vugebk1zob2fw2hgxiftjg1z; cPER=!SmE/fvI1sjF1DqtSzYfA84hhMFmKdR+VmPTaX1WlhB8KHfkS3iP2fO2FK2iyUzwiDyupy85iZItfoeo=; _ga=GA1.2.534681471.1587587675; _gid=GA1.2.113108587.1588205109',
            'Host': 'www.borsaistanbul.com',
            'Origin' : 'null',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode' : 'navigate', 
            'Sec-Fetch-Site' : 'same-origin',
            'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            // 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'
        },
        /* GZIP true for most of the websites now, disable it if you don't need it */
        gzip: true
    })
    .pipe(file)
    .on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`The file is finished downloading.`);
        resolve();
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
    })
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`Something happened: ${error}`);
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround if anyone tries to accomplish a similar thing. 
I've downloaded the file with puppeteer libraries.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,slowMo: 250});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.borsaistanbul.com/veriler/verileralt/hisse-senetleri-piyasasi-verileri/piyasa-verileri');
  page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));
  await page.waitForSelector('#TextContent_C001_lbtnUyeBazindaGunlukIslemSiralamasi');
  await page.click('#TextContent_C001_lbtnUyeBazindaGunlukIslemSiralamasi');
  await browser.close();
})();
```